# How to have azure cli not ask for password while creating a new vm from specialized Windows image?

Tags: azure, azure-vm

```
az vm create \
--resource-group RG1\
--name sts-test-1 \
--image "/subscriptions/<guid>/resourceGroups/RG1/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/windows_sts/images/windows_sts_image/versions/0.0.6" \
--specialized true
```

Admin Password:

Confirm Admin Password:

I was expecting it to not ask for password as the image is already specified as *specialized*  . I tried passing in the password via a file using  command < pass.txt which results in another message.

ERROR: Please specify password in non-interactive mode.

Need a way to either bypass the password or not pass it at all.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same results as below:***

[image]

You can pass the **Admin Password** in the command while creating the VM like below:

```
az vm create
--resource-group RG!
--name MyVm
--image Win2022AzureEditionCore
--location westeurope
--admin-username Name
--admin-password Password
```

I am able to create Vm successfully by passing the **`Admin Password`** in the command like below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah this worked. Thanks for quick help. I still am confused why it shows no option to pass username and password for specialized image in the UI but needs that here with cli.